# Convert image dimension in percentage to pixels

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an `img` element inside a `div` element as below:

```
<div class='img-container col-md-12' id='box'> 
    <img src='/img/sample.png' id='srcImg' style='width:100%'>
</div>
```

Here i am trying to fit the loaded large image into division element completely from an existing image using canvas, which works fine. Now i am trying to get the image dimensions as rendered in the browser using:

```
var $srcImg = document.getElementById('srcImg');
var utilCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
utilCanvas.width = $srcImg.naturalWidth;
utilCanvas.height = $srcImg.naturalHeight;
var ctx = utilCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage($srcImg, 0, 0);

var img = new Image();
img.id = 'tempImg';
img.src = utilCanvas.toDataURL();
img.style.width = '100%';
$srcImg.parentNode.insertBefore(img, $srcImg.nextSibling);

// Get the rendered image dimensions
var w = $('#tempImg').innerWidth();
var h = $('#tempImg').innerHeight();
print('Width: '+w+' ,Height: '+h);
```

Which is giving output as: **Width: 100 ,Height:0**.

When I am trying the same thing in browser console window, then it's giving me correct results.

What will be the correct way to do the same?

Comment: I was incorrect

Comment: @JoeWarner no issues :)

Comment: please check if `('#tempImg').clientWidth;` works

Comment: @flamelite https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzrNvy?editors=1111 this pen shows that it logs the correct values does your containing element have height?

Comment: @moghya clientWidth is giving undefined

Comment: @JoeWarner not height is not defined.I want the rendered image width and height.

Comment: Methods `innerHeight` and `innerWidth` return the height/width of the element, including top and bottom padding, in pixels as stated in the documentation for [innerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) and [innerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/). From the example @JoeWarner posted, I can see the methods returning correct values.

Comment: @Adriani6 but height is 0.

Comment: @flamelite That means the image is not there when you run your function :)

Comment: @Adriani6 i have updated my question.

Comment: @flamelite See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your height/width check inside `img.onload = function(){ //code }`. Images always load asynchronously.

```
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = utilCanvas.toDataURL();
    img.id = "imgId";
    img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    img.onload = function () {

       //  code -> use imgId to grab the image..

    }
```

Comment: that would give the natural dimensions of the image.

Comment: No. It returns the correct size of the element, your problem appears now to be elsewhere in your code. This answer is correct because you can't check the dimensions of the image until it's loaded, simple flow of operation... your problem now is that you want to probably add it as a hidden element but that's a completely different problem than the one in your question.

Comment: i am not hiding the new img element.

Comment: Exactly... that's your problem. It needs to be rendered as an HTML element not just in code. You won't know the rendered size until it renders. You seem to be wanting to skip a lot of important steps.

Comment: Yeah, that's right @Adriani6. I tried to find make a call back after render but failed, do u have any idea how to do the same.

Comment: @flamelite See the code snippet I added. Down-voting an answer for your misunderstanding isn't really fair as your initial question was answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166783/discussion-between-flamelite-and-adriani6).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the image is not yet loaded when you apply that script. Try to put it into a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` or use some other way to run it *after*  the image has been loaded if it's loaded even later.

Comment: The image here in division element is dynamically loaded, i will update my question.